# Finding the .exe of a Click Once App - Task Scheduler

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, scheduled-tasks, clickonce

All,

I have a C# console application that was published as a click once app. I installed it on the server and I can run it from the command line fine like this:

```
C:\Users\slinky66>c:\Tasks\MemberInterestFollowUp.application
```

So I entered the same path into Task Scheduler and when it attempted to run the program, I received the error **2147942593**, which sounds like it's a problem with the file type that I am trying to execute not being a .exe.

How can I get the Task Scheduler to run this program?

**Options**

1. It looks like I need to find the .exe but that is not easy so far, at least for me

2, Get the Task Scheduler to open "cmd" with the argument: C:\Users\slinky66>c:\Tasks\MemberInterestFollowUp.application

I also looked here for the .exe but I don't know if I am even looking in the right place

```
Directory of C:\Users\slinky66\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\ADQQDL82.XPT\GBHHHGOJ.V9
5

07/26/2013  07:04 PM    <DIR>          .
07/26/2013  07:04 PM    <DIR>          ..
07/24/2013  08:23 PM    <DIR>          enti..work_b77a5c561934e089_0004.0004_non
e_15b5b678d0f5bc44
07/26/2013  07:04 PM    <DIR>          manifests
07/26/2013  02:28 PM    <DIR>          memb...exe_c7d043b2afe157c4_0001.0000_non
e_d7a3c411cb9480bb
07/26/2013  07:04 PM    <DIR>          memb...exe_c7d043b2afe157c4_0001.0000_non
e_d7a3c411cb9480bc
07/26/2013  02:28 PM    <DIR>          memb..tion_c7d043b2afe157c4_0001.0000_cc5
174db8dff3387
07/26/2013  07:04 PM    <DIR>          memb..tion_c7d043b2afe157c4_0001.0000_cc5
174dc8e7e4347
07/24/2013  08:23 PM    <DIR>          micr..look_71e9bce111e9429c_000c.0000_non
e_c75b686a41ceb954
07/24/2013  08:23 PM    <DIR>          office_71e9bce111e9429c_000c.0000_none_f2
6680d4e27df7a2
07/24/2013  08:23 PM    <DIR>          stdole_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_0007.0000_none_33
3059d4a751806f
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
              11 Dir(s)  181,672,923,136 bytes free
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering to your problem and not to your question - try add this line to the task scheduler:

```
start c:\Tasks\MemberInterestFollowUp.application
```

Answering to your question - looks like the answer is [here](http://ianpicknell.blogspot.com/2010/03/launching-clickonce-application.html).

Comment: This didn't work for me. I tried using schtasks and still didn't want to run.

Answer (score 0):

It appears if you make a .bat file with this command:

```
start <path to your .application file>
```

and point the task scheduler to the .bat file, it works on Windows 2008 R2 enterprise.